# JPQL inner join and left join

Tags: jpa, join, jpql, querydsl

I know what joins are and how to use them in plain SQL but i can't find any explanation of internet to query object with relations. I use entity,getList.size() to query objects that has oneToMany or ManyToMany associations with my entity. I'm wondering is there any way to query object with all his relations.

```
public Person
@OneToMany
List<Cat>
@ManyToMany
List<DormRoom>
```

what is do to get all object is;

```
Person p=PersonDAO.getWithId(1L);
p.getCats.size();
p.getsDormRooms.size();
```

Now i'm wondering the get fully evulated object with JPQL, CriteriaBuilder and maybe with QueryDSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a fetch join:

```
select distinct p from Person p left join fetch p.cats left join fetch p.dormRooms
where p.id = :id
```

Beware though:

- in Hibernate at least, that will only work if at most 1 of the collections is a bag (i.e. a list without any specified order column).
- that will create a query returning the cartesian product of cats * dormRooms. So if a person has 100 cats and 100 dormRooms, 10,000 rows will be retrieved.

Comment: So basically, i need to multiple queries to get full object. What i'm gonna suppose to do with 10.000 rows.

Comment: No, the edited query above will return a single Person entity, with all its 100 dormRooms and 100 cats populated. But the underlying SQL query that Hibernate will execute will return 10000 rows, due to how SQL works.

Comment: And with more relationships, queries with multiple joins cause more and more performance overhead. Is there any other optimal solution for these cases?

Comment: I would say that if you need to load a bunch of toMany associations, then you probably have a UX design problem. It's quite rare to display, on a single page, a person with all his friend, dormrooms, cats, phone numbers, hobbies, etc. etc. But if that's really needed, then what you have is fine. It will cause one query per association to be executed, which is not bad.